# How can i use "Add-Migration" command in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm doing a Udemy course using Visual Studio 2015(same as the course)

At some point I've to use `Add-Migration` command, but somehow I can't do it.

This is the error i get:

[image]

I've searched for similar questions that said I had to install **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools**, but when I try to install a version that supports `Add-Migration` command, I get this error:

> The 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 2.1.0' package requires NuGet client version '3.6.0' or above, but the current NuGet version is '3.6.0-rtm-2511'. To upgrade NuGet, please go to http://docs.nuget.org/consume/installing-nuget

This is my `project.json` file:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0"
  },
  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },
  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "Areas/**/Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Do I have to change the **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools** version directly on my `project.json` file?

Comment: Preferably find a different course. `project.json` is *very* outdated, as is `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 2.1.0`.

Comment: You can use  the 'Package Manager Console', the same you used for your EF command, to [install or update NuGet packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-powershell). I don't know, if VS2015 has it already build it, but with VS2019 there is a GUI for this too. Right click your solution, then select (something along the lines) 'manage NuGet packages' (i use a german translation, not sure how it's named for you).

Comment: That was the first version that supported "Add-Migration" command, according to Visual Studio, so i've tried to install that version instead, but i can go to version 5.1.0

Comment: @nbokmans, my question is how in the course they can do it, and i can't using exactly the same settings...

Answer (score 0):

You have to [update your installation of NuGet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/troubleshooting/questions/nuget-update) as 3.6.0 is pretty old and outdated.

Comment: Sorry, didn't help

Comment: What version did you install? Did you restart your visual studio after the installation?

Also, why are you using Visual Studio 2015? You could upgrade to [Visual Studio 2019 Community](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/de/downloads/), which is free.

Comment: The only thing i had on updates section was this file named: "AspNetWebFrameworksToolsVS2015-KB4339279"

I'm using VS2015 cause it's the same as the course, and since above versions doesn't support project.json file anymore, in new versions all the project.json file content is made differently, and that confuses me a little

Comment: It's hard for me to help you find a solution as i can't really reproduce your problem because of the outdated software you are using.

I advise you to search for a different course as this one uses very outdated technologies (.net core 1.0). You'll find plenty of resources (also a lot for free) on this topic as ASP.net core is a popular framework nowadays.

Comment: Thank you anyway, friend